# Neural network unable to predict y=2x relationship

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am getting a loss of `13332936704` and with every epoch tje loss is not decreasing very much. The output is `0.74`.

```
Import tensorflow as tf
x=[]
y=[]
For i in range(10000):
  x.append(i)
  y append(i*2)
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,input_shape=(1,),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(28,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x,y,epochs=150,batch_size=32)
model.predict([2])
```

I want to deploy the neural network in a big project, but it is not simply predicting normal relation. I tried rerunning the cells and also changing `y=2x`. However, it is still not predicting.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Capitalization matters in Python and `y append(i*2)` would surely produce an error. Please show an actual [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Your model's last layer is sigmoid, so the outputs of the model can only be between 0 and 1.

[image]

And how can you expect it to ever learn how to produce `2*i` (which is between 0 and 20000 in your case)?

Either try to remove the `activation='sigmoid'`, or normalize your input/output data to be in range between 0 and 1